# How can I maintain a permanent shade lawn?

Tags: grass, fescue, shade

My Fescue Grass does fine here in my shady South Carolina yard. However, it needs to be re-seeded every year or it gets bare patches. Are there any alternatives that do not involve buying more seed every year (besides chopping down my trees and planting a sunny grass or naturalizing the area)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a type of fescue called RTF (Rhizomatous Tall Fescue) which I think works better than most common types of fescue.  It has the ability to send out runners underground that will fill in bare patches over time.  I've had it for a couple of years in my front yard and have been very happy with it.